# Facebook SDK Graphrequest returns null

Tags: java, c#, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Using Facebook SDK 4.4 in Xamarin.Android project. I have the following method :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 LoginButton button = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.FbLoginBtn);
 button.SetReadPermissions(new List<string>{ "public_profile", "email" });
 mCallBackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
 button.RegisterCallback(mCallBackManager, this);
 button.Click += (o, e)=> 
  {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken, this);
    Bundle paramenters = new Bundle();
    paramenters.PutString("fields", "id,name,email,first_name,last_name");
    request.Parameters = paramenters;
    request.ExecuteAsync();
  };
}

public void OnCompleted(JSONObject @object, GraphResponse response)
{
  if (@object != null)
  {
   userEmail.Text = @object.ToString();
  }
 }
```

The problem with the above code is that, in the `OnCompleted` method, the `JSONObject` always return null when i log in to my facebook account from the app. But when i click the button again to ***Log Out***, i get the proper json with all fields that i specified.

My question is, why is the `GraphRequest` returning null upon log-in but successfully returns the JSON upon log out?